# DMN / Camunda Modeller: how to define a Parallel Multi Instance Result

Tags: bpmn, camunda, camunda-modeler, dmn

I want to include a decision table in my process.

As the input is a list of elements, I want to call it for each element in parallel.

When I look at the output it only includes one entry. So it seems that each execution overrides the previous one. 
Example: `[{pricePerProcessInstance=150.0, pricePerTask=0.0}]`

I suspect I do something wrong in the definition.

Here is the definition for it:

[image: dmn definition]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe that the Execution Listener (1) should solve your problem.

You could configure an end execution listener as depicted [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nviPI.png)

Please take a look at the example implementation of class defined in the listener section above.

```
public class MyService implements JavaDelegate {

  @Override
  public void execute(DelegateExecution delegateExecution) {
    List<String> resultList = (List<String>) delegateExecution.getVariable("resultList");

    if (resultList == null) {
      resultList = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    resultList.add((String) delegateExecution.getVariable("processPrices"));

    delegateExecution.setVariable("resultList", resultList);

  }

}
```

In every execution of the decision table the result variable `processPrices` will be added to the `ArrayList` `resultList`.

(1) https://docs.camunda.org/manual/latest/user-guide/process-engine/delegation-code/#execution-listener